# Flutter refresh/SetState on route (not main page)

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to learn Flutter and I'm making my first app. Because of that I'm almost certain my question is dumb or very basic.

I have a very simple app that loads info from an API on the main page, it also has a button which redirects the user to a secondary config page or route. In this interface the user may select or deselect some items (this is very similar to the second part of the first flutter tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#4 ). The problem I'm currently having is that when the user taps on some item, the icon doesn't change accordingly **unless I hotReload the app** in which case the icon shows as expected, meaning the rest of the logic is working more or less correctly. Im calling the setState method and I know it's calling the build widget yet the icons remain unchanged unless I hot reload the app.

I have implemented the pull to refresh functionality, this doesn't seem to work eihter. It doesn't update the data from the API, I need to go back to the main page and then enter again to the config no see the current data.

**The question basically is ¿What needs to be done to refresh the "secondary route" when the user taps some element on it?**

Part of the code used...

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print("corrió build");
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
            actions: [
              IconButton(onPressed: _irAConfig, icon: const Icon(Icons.settings))
            ],
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder<List<Noticia>>(
            future: futureNoticias,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return RefreshIndicator(
                child: _listViewNoticias(snapshot),
                onRefresh: _pullRefreshNoticias,
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }

void _irAConfig() {
    futureSecciones = fuenteSecciones().getSecciones();
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Secciones"),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Seccion>>(
          future: futureSecciones,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot ssSecciones) {
            print("builder de irAConfig");
            return RefreshIndicator(
              child: _listViewSecciones(ssSecciones),
              onRefresh: _pullRefreshSecciones,
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    }));
  }

Widget _listViewSecciones(AsyncSnapshot ssSecciones) {
    print("_listViewSecciones");
    if (ssSecciones.hasData) {
      return GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
        elements: ssSecciones.data,
        groupBy: (element) => element.idPortal,
        groupComparator: (value1, value2) => value1.compareTo(value2),
        itemComparator: (item1, item2) =>
            item1.descCategoria.compareTo(item2.descCategoria),
        order: GroupedListOrder.ASC,
        useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
        groupSeparatorBuilder: (String value) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            value,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext c, element) {
          return _buildRow(element);
        },
      );
    } else {
      return const Center(
        child: Text("Cargando..."),
      );
    }
  }

  Widget _buildRow(Seccion seccion) {
    print ("buildRow");
    final alreadySaved = _saved.contains(seccion);
    return Card(
      elevation: 5.0,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5.0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      child: ListTile(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 1),
        //leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        title: Text(
          seccion.descCategoria,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        ),
        trailing: Icon(
            alreadySaved ? Icons.check_box : Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            if (alreadySaved) {
              _saved.remove(seccion);
            } else {
              _saved.add(seccion);
            }
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your code, but there might be a few reasons why icon is not changing:

- You are not calling `setState()` method after changing the variable value of that icon.
- You put icon into wrong variable, and you are not passing it into build
  This is how you make some widget change its value:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Example()));
}

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  IconData icon = 0;

  changeIcon() {
    icon = Icons.anotherIcon; // < == change icon
    setState(); // < == call set state method
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Center(
        child: Icon(
          icon
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to get a concrete answer, please, provide a simplified version of your code with all `widget` related code included.

Comment: Yeah, you are not wrong. My problem was that I was using a StatelessWidget instead of a Stateful one... One I changed the code to use Stateful widget, eveything worked as expected.

Comment: you can mark this answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

In case some is trying to figure this one out. Read this: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#managing-state

Basically if you need the page to change, for instance as a result of user interaction, you need to use use StatefulWidget instead of Stateless...